# Adding 175,000 records, one by one, to LocalDB takes several minutes

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wrote a [scraper](http://pastebin.com/twePmbbc) to download 10 years of stock data for ~3200 stocks. Each stock gets downloaded to its own text file, which looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/FtPbgSXQ).

Now I am trying to populate my local database with the data that I downloaded. It does work but it is extremely slow. I add the records one at a time. So if one stock  has 2500 data points then I call AddRow() 2500 times.

I started with parameters and now I am using the Entity Framework. Both are really slow. To give you an idea, this is the function I am using to populate the database:

```
    private DateTime ParseDate(string date) {
        string[] parts = date.Split('-');
        int year = Int16.Parse(parts[0]);
        int month = Int16.Parse(parts[1]);
        int day = Int16.Parse(parts[2]);
        return new DateTime(year, month, day);
    }

    public void PopulateFromCSVs(IStockHistory repository)
    {
        string symbolsPath = scraperDir + @"\symbols\symbols.txt";
        string[] symbols = File.ReadAllText(symbolsPath).Split(',');

        int count = symbols.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            string line;
            int curLineNum = 0;
            string curFile = scraperDir + @"\history\" + symbols[i] + ".txt";
            if (!File.Exists(curFile))
                continue;
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(curFile))
            {
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    curLineNum++;
                    string[] row = line.Split(',');
                    if (curLineNum > 1)
                    {
                        repository.AddStockRecord(new StockRecord()
                        {
                            Symbol = symbols[i],
                            RecordDate = ParseDate(row[0]),
                            OpenValue = float.Parse(row[1]),
                            HighValue = float.Parse(row[2]),
                            LowValue = float.Parse(row[3]),
                            CloseValue = float.Parse(row[4]),
                            Volume = float.Parse(row[5]),
                            AdjustedCloseValue = float.Parse(row[6])
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It could be better but it's not insane. That is, there is no code there that would take a long time for no reason. To test the function I only had it populate data for 5 stocks (175,000 rows). It did add data to the database but it was incredibly slow.

[image]

1. Is it going so slow because I am add one row at a time or because the database is not partitioned properly?
2. Any idea why the values get entered as e.g. 74.37 but show up in the database as 74.37000274658...? The database and C# types are just "float"

As something to compare it too, the scripts that download and concatenate the data can read through every record in every file in just a couple seconds.

[edit] sorry, its more like ~17,500, not 175,000.

Comment: Do you have any sort of index or primary key on the table ? What is usually slow on INSERT is rebuild of an index. Don't use float for prices - use decimal(18,5) instead. Also SQL server has nice feature of bulk upload which is principal difference in speed and is something you should look into.

Comment: OndrejSvejdar is referring to `BULK INSERT`:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: Is your table indexed in which you are inserting the data??Suggestion: As you have text files use Bulk Insert to insert text file data directly into database

Comment: Try wrapping your loop with a `TransactionScope` so that the rows aren't committed one-by-one.

Comment: The table uses primary key(Symbol, RecordDate) for it's primary key. I didn't do anything else to it. I will do that with switching floats to decimal(18,5)

Comment: I added TransactionScope but it still takes like 60-90 seconds to get through just the first file (~3500 rows).

Comment: Don't use Entity Framework for bulk inserts. try another approach.

Comment: regarding price values - it is because of float type, as other mentioned you should use decimal.

Comment: doing BULK INSERT had a dramatic effect! It can insert 3500 lines in less than a second now whereas it used to take over a minute!

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, and processing 175,000 rows and creating individual arrays for all of the data may be causing memory contention.
2. Floating point numbers are not perfect for all numbers. The database may be using a floating point format that does not handle those numbers correctly or is faster.